# How to format a date as part of a string in Teradata?

Tags: sql, date, teradata

I'm trying to derive a filename in Teradata.

The format should be like this:

> `X_<YYYYMMDDHHMI>_Y.dat`

This is how I'm trying to achieve it:

> `'X_' || CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMI') (CHAR (12)) AS VARCHAR(50))   || '_Y.dat'`

But I keep getting a bunch of syntax errors.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parens are all out of whack, I think.

```
SELECT
'X_' || CAST((CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) (FORMAT 'YYYYMMDDHHMI')) AS VARCHAR(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your TD version supports TO_CHAR you might use it instead:

```
TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '"X_"YYYYMMDDHHMI"_Y"')
```